# How to add a simple navigation bar in a xml layout file?

Tags: android, xml, navigationbar

I am writing an AccessibilityService, which opens a fullscreen view via the WindowManager on a certain event. I am currently designing the view to be opened. I'd like to add a navigation bar at the top of this view, as it is automatically added by Android Studio when you create an empty activity, for example. This navigation bar should not contain any buttons or the like. However, it should have exactly the same size as it is given to a default activity by Android or Android Studio. Below is the result I would like to have. I don't know with which xml element I can add this bar/navigation bar.

[image: Preview of what I am trying to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to your activity :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/HeaderBar"
        app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
        android:elevation="4dp"
       >
              <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="DataCollector"
                 android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
       </toolbar>
```

And then in your activity in onCreate() method add this :

```
private Toolbar mTopToolbar;

mTopToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mTopToolbar);
```

Comment: support library instead of androidx libraries in 2020?

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I am not working with Activities. I wrote an AccessibilityService that listens to events and then uses the WindowManager to add a view to the display. So I have no Activity class. Your solution also doesn't seem to make sure that all other elements in my view are automatically placed below the navigation bar. Instead, they partially overlap the Navigation Bar.

Comment: You can add this to your windowManager

Comment: The method `setSupportActionBar()` is not available in an AccessibilityService.